# Deploy standard field labels using Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, standard-field

We want to use some of Product object **standard fields** and just change field labels to make them more tailored for our organization.

For example: `Product Code` -> `EAN Code`

This can be achieved by going to Rename Tabs and Labels but since we are using pipelines and have many developer orgs we want to avoid manual steps.

**The question is: how to retrieve and deploy this using `mdapi` of `sfdx`?**

What I tried was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Product2-en_US</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Product2.ProductCode</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Product2.ProductCode</members>
        <name>CustomFieldTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

But this retrieves the field without the label.

When adding it manually to CustomField metadata file I get following error:
`Cannot specify label on standard field (3:13)`

I also tried retrieving just the Product2's `CustomObjectTranslation` using following package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>Product2-en_US</members>
    <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
</types>
```

And this returns empty file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObjectTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The metadata you want is the `CustomObjectTranslation`.

It'll include metadata similar to this example (from a renaming of the Account object to Organization, and similar renamings at the field level):

```
    <fields>
        <caseValues>
            <plural>false</plural>
            <value>Organization Number</value>
        </caseValues>
        <name>account_number</name>
        <startsWith>Vowel</startsWith>
    </fields>
```

The `CustomObject` and `CustomField` metadata won't change, because you cannot actually alter the label of the standard field. Your renaming is encapsulated in the `CustomObjectTranslation`, and you can deploy it into other orgs via that vehicle.

Comment: Thanks David for your comment. Tried this with no success - empty file is returned. I will update my question to note that

Comment: I think CustomObjectTranslation works similiar to profiles - retrieves just the translations for other members in the package xml - at least this is how it works for custom fields.

Comment: I am able to retrieve via below with VS Code but can't deploy, any thoughts?
`<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name></types>`

Comment: @Usman Please open a new question.

Answer (score 3):

As per pointed out by Salesforce Support when I asked them directly,

You should add the following extract to your package.xml file:

```
<types>
        <members>Product-en_US</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
</types>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

**Edit for clarity:** Notice there's no "2" in the line

```
<members>Product-en_US</members>
```